# How to count SQL rows

Tags: sql

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Stack WHERE Id = 33478 GROUP BY SID

Output:

(No column name)
1
4
```

For the result; there are two row. How can I return it 2? (count of rows)

Are there any way like below:

```
Select COUNT(SELECT count(*) FROM Stack WHERE ContentId = 33478 GROUP BY SID) ....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID) FROM Stack WHERE Id = 33478
```

Comment: +1... Beat me to it!  First time my answer got rejected because it was an *exact duplicate* of a previous answer...

Comment: I didn't even know of this feature - nice!